# Me surge el :ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «tb_material»

Tags: sql

Alguien podria revisar las sentencias SQL siguientes

```
-- Creación de tablas
BEGIN WORK;
CREATE TABLE manufacturing.tb_warehouse (
        wh_code CHARACTER(5),
        wh_name CHARACTER VARYING(40) NOT NULL,
        wh_address CHARACTER VARYING(120),
        wh_city CHARACTER VARYING(25),
        wh_country CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
        wh_account_no CHARACTER VARYING(40),
        created_by_user CHARACTER VARYING(10) DEFAULT'CV_SYSTEM' NOT NULL,
        created_date DATE,
        updated_date DATE,
        CONSTRAINT pk_tb_warehouse PRIMARY KEY (wh_code)
);

CREATE TABLE manufacturing.tb_transaction_type (
        trans_type_code CHARACTER(5),
        trans_type_desc CHARACTER VARYING(60) NOT NULL,
        created_by_user CHARACTER VARYING(10) DEFAULT'CV_SYSTEM' NOT NULL,
        created_date DATE,
        updated_date DATE,
        CONSTRAINT pk_tb_transaction_type PRIMARY KEY (trans_type_code)
);
CREATE TABLE manufacturing.tb_material (
        material_code CHARACTER(5),
        material_name CHARACTER VARYING(60) NOT NULL,
        material_unit_price NUMERIC (12, 2),
        parent_material_code CHARACTER(5),
        material_type CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT'DEFAULT' NOT NULL,
        created_by_user CHARACTER VARYING(10) DEFAULT'CV_SYSTEM' NOT NULL,
        created_date DATE,
        updated_date DATE,
        CONSTRAINT pk_tb_material PRIMARY KEY(material_code),
        CONSTRAINT fk_tb_material FOREIGN KEY(parent_material_code) REFERENCES manufacturing.tb_material
);

CREATE TABLE manufacturing.tb_lot (
        lot_number CHARACTER(10),
        lot_status CHARACTER VARYING(15) NOT NULL,
        lot_material_code CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
        lot_quantity NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
        created_by_user CHARACTER VARYING(10) DEFAULT'CV_SYSTEM',
        created_date DATE,
        updated_date DATE,
        CONSTRAINT pk_tb_lot PRIMARY KEY(lot_number),
        CONSTRAINT fk_tb_lot FOREIGN KEY(lot_material_code) REFERENCES manufacturing.tb_material(parent_material_code),
        CONSTRAINT ck_lot_status CHECK(lot_status = 'GOOD''QA TEST''IN TRANSIT''BLOCKED')
);

CREATE TABLE manufacturing.tb_transaction (
        trans_id INTEGER,
        trans_wh_code CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
        trans_lot_number CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
        trans_type_code CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
        trans_process_order CHARACTER VARYING(15),
        trans_quantity NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
        trans_debit_credit_flag CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
        trans_shipping_num CHARACTER VARYING(12),
        created_by_user CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT'CV_SYSTEM',
        created_date DATE,
        updated_date DATE,
        CONSTRAINT pk_trans_id PRIMARY KEY(trans_id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_trans_wh_code FOREIGN KEY(trans_wh_code) REFERENCES tb_warehouse,
        CONSTRAINT fk_trans_lot_number FOREIGN KEY(trans_lot_number) REFERENCES tb_lot,
        CONSTRAINT fk_trans_type_code FOREIGN KEY(trans_type_code) REFERENCES manufacturing.tb_transaction(tb_transaction_type),
        CONSTRAINT ck_trans_debit_credit_flag CHECK(trans_debit_credit = 'D' OR 'C')
);

COMMIT WORK;
```

Comment: ¿Qué gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: No creo que sea indispensable meter la creación de tablas en una transacción, pero como veas. Lo que esto viendo es que en la última tabla tienes dos foreign key donde mencionas la tabla referenciada, pero no cuál es el campo al que hace referencia...

Comment: Utilizo PgAdmin.

Comment: Para eso existen los compiladores.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes aquí:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_lot_status CHECK(lot_status = 'GOOD''QA TEST''IN TRANSIT''BLOCKED')"
```

Yo lo he puesto así:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_lot_status CHECK(lot_status='GOOD' OR lot_status='QA TEST' OR lot_status='IN TRANSIT' OR lot_status='BLOCKED')
```